# Why the swagger doesn't open in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, .net-6.0

Well, I was doing a DDD project, specifically using redis, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

The problem is, the swagger doesn't appear to me, it fails, but when I make requests in postman it works normally.

Thats the error:

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.ITagsMetadata' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultTagsSelector(ApiDescription apiDescription)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultSortKeySelector(ApiDescription apiDescription) in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll:token 0x600012d+0x0
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) in System.Linq.dll:token 0x600040b+0x10
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) in System.Linq.dll:token 0x6000401+0x0
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) in System.Linq.dll:token 0x6000402+0x0
     at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext() in System.Linq.dll:token 0x6000391+0x3d
     at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) in System.Linq.dll:token 0x6000366+0x2b
     at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`2.GetEnumerator() in System.Linq.dll:token 0x600035f+0x0
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll:token 0x60000f8+0x3a
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath) in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll:token 0x60000f6+0xe6
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll:token 0x6000009+0xe2
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll:token 0x60000aa+0x82
```

Startup file (**ConfigureServices**):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddRedisContext(Configuration);
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Basket.Api", Version = "v1" 
        });
});
```

My method in extension method class:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRedisContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {                
            options.Configuration = config["CacheSettings:ConnectionString"];
        });

        services.AddScoped<IBasketRepository, BasketRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IBasketService, BasketService>();

        return services;
 }
```

The Package reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Basket.Infra.Data\Basket.Infra.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also commented the lines referring to redis and it still gave the same error. So it's almost certainly something involving the swagger.

Comment: Can you please post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) somewhere?

Comment: Ok, following the divide and conquer strategy, I commented the extension method part of redis and it kept giving an error, I commented the swagger part and stopped the error, but also obviously the swagger didn't open.

Comment: Could you show the list of `PackageReference` in your csproj?

Comment: I edited the question with PackageReference.

Comment: I got something, but I believe it's not really a solution, but it's at least working. I simply downgraded to version 6.2.2 and it worked. But there's a project with the same version in my solution and it's working, it doesn't make sense to me lol

Comment: Same issue here, upgraded swashbuckle to the latest version. Also updated to .NET 6.0 and getting

Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.ITagsMetadata' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0

Comment: I don't know if it helps you doing that, but if you downgrade you swashbuckle to the version 6.2.2 could works. Because for me it working good.

Comment: I have the same situation, maybe the latest Swashbuckle version 6.2.3 is broken and not working with net6.0, scenarios I tested: net5.0 and Swashbuckle 6.2.3 = working; net6.0 and Swashbuckle 6.2.3 = NOT working; net6.0 and Swashbuckle 6.2.2 = working;

Comment: I found this GitHub issue which is related to net6.0 and the "ITagsMetadata" part of the error message: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2192

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it was the SDK not running the proper net6.0 version.

While the whole project was using new net6.0 NuGet packages, the local SDK on that one machine I was working on was still net5.0. After installing .net6.0, Swashbuckle 6.2.3 was working again, and all was as expected.

Comment: At properties of my project the target framework is net6.0 and at the terminal I wrote dotnet --list-sdks and appeared the 6.0.300 version. Dou you know something that can I do to use the swagger?